# Color de fondo según la clase del DIV

Tags: javascript, botón, clase, color

Estoy practicando y quiero mejorar el código, ya que es largo y me gustaría que quedara mejor.

Tengo un **grid** con seis (06) botones, cada uno de un color. Al hacer clic en el botón "negro" todo el fondo del DIV que ocupa todo el ancho de la página cambia a negro. Hasta ahí todo bien.

[image]

La cosa es que tengo mucho código JS, uno para cada botón, y me gustaría simplificarlo (cada botón tiene una clase con el color al que cambia).

```js
function cabezaNegro(colorCabeza) {
  var cabeza = document.getElementById("cabeza");
  cabeza.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

function cabezaBlanco(colorCabeza) {
  var cabeza = document.getElementById("cabeza");
  cabeza.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

function cabezaBeige(colorCabeza) {
  var cabeza = document.getElementById("cabeza");
  cabeza.style.backgroundColor = "beige";
}

function cabezaAzul(colorCabeza) {
  var cabeza = document.getElementById("cabeza");
  cabeza.style.backgroundColor = "darkblue";
}

function cabezaVerde(colorCabeza) {
  var cabeza = document.getElementById("cabeza");
  cabeza.style.backgroundColor = "darkolivegreen";
}

function cabezaMarron(colorCabeza) {
  var cabeza = document.getElementById("cabeza");
  cabeza.style.backgroundColor = "class";
}
```

```html
<div class="cabeza" id="cabeza">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button onclick="cabezaNegro(this)" class="black"></button>
    <button onclick="cabezaBlanco(this)" class="white"></button>
    <button onclick="cabezaBeige(this)" class="beige"></button>
    <button onclick="cabezaAzul(this)" class="darkblue"></button>
    <button onclick="cabezaVerde(this)" class="darkolivegreen"></button>
    <button onclick="cabezaMarron(this)" class="brown"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo dinamico de esta forma:

```js
function changeColor(color) {
    var color = color.className;
    var cabeza = document.getElementById('cabeza'); 
    cabeza.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabeza" id="cabeza">  
  <br><br><br><br>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <button onclick="changeColor(this)" class="black">Black</button>
            <button onclick="changeColor(this)" class="white">White</button>
            <button onclick="changeColor(this)" class="beige">Beige</button>
            <button onclick="changeColor(this)" class="darkblue">Dark Blue</button>
            <button onclick="changeColor(this)" class="darkolivegreen">darkolivegreen</button>
            <button onclick="changeColor(this)" class="brown">brown</button>            
          </div>        
    </div>
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Poco a poco aprendiendo! Gracias de nuevo de verdad!

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien tu pregunta, una idea podría ser usar una sola función y pasarle el color como parámetro, por ejemplo:

```
function cambiarColor(colorCabeza) {
    var cabeza = document.getElementById("cabeza"); 
    cabeza.style.backgroundColor = colorCabeza;
}
```

Y en cada botón colocar el color como parámetro:

```
<button onclick="cambiarColor('black')" class="black"></button>
<button onclick="cambiarColor('white')" class="white"></button>
```

etc...

Hay varias otras formas en que se puede hacer, pero como tu idea es simplificar el código que ya tienes, esa podría ser una salida.

Comment: Lo pruebo mañana en cuanto pueda! no había caido! estaba intentando "coger como color" la clase que está ya nombrada con el mismo

Comment: Claro, en ese caso puedes tomar el className como indica Gerardo en la otra respuesta

Comment: Funciona a la perfección! Muchas gracias de verdad! :D

Answer (score 0):

aplica esta función y en `onclick` dejas el nombre de la función `cambiarColor`

```js
  function cambiarColor(colorCabeza) {
    var cabeza = document.getElementById("cabeza"); 
    cabeza.style.backgroundColor = colorCabeza.style.backgroundColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabeza" id="cabeza">              
        <div class="wrapper">
            <button onclick="cambiarColor(this)" class="black"></button>
            <button onclick="cambiarColor(this)" class="white"></button>
            <button onclick="cambiarColor(this)" class="beige"></button>
            <button onclick="cambiarColor(this)" class="darkblue"></button>
            <button onclick="cambiarColor(this)" class="darkolivegreen"></button>
            <button onclick="cambiarColor(this)" class="brown"></button>            
          </div>        
    </div>
```