# Simplificar código de condicionales

Tags: javascript

Gracias a vuestros aportes y consejos sobre este tema:

[Color de fondo según la clase del DIV](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/420545/color-de-fondo-seg%c3%ban-la-clase-del-div/420549?noredirect=1#comment750909_420549)

Ahora estoy siguiendo en mi "Aplicación sobre conjuntar ropa".

Ya teniendo todos los cambios etc, os pongo como va el proyecto en Codepen:

https://codepen.io/jmgarcia34/pen/poEGZzw

Dependiendo de los colores que se elijan para cada prenda de ropa, el programa te da un pequeño comentario sobre si está "bien" o "mal" o se puede mejorar el conjunto.

¿se puede simplificar algo o está medianamente correcto?

```
function conjuntar(porcentaje) {
    var cabeza = document.getElementById('cabeza');
    var cuerpo = document.getElementById('cuerpo');
    var pantalones = document.getElementById('pantalones');
    var zapatillas = document.getElementById('zapatillas');
    var colorCabeza = cabeza.style.backgroundColor;
    var colorCuerpo = cuerpo.style.backgroundColor;  
    var colorPantalones = pantalones.style.backgroundColor;  
    var colorZapatillas = zapatillas.style.backgroundColor;  

    if ((colorCuerpo == "darkblue") && (colorPantalones == "black") || (colorCuerpo == "black") && (colorPantalones == "darkblue")) {
        alert("¿Azul con Negro? ¡No por favor!");
    } else if ((colorCuerpo == "darkblue") && (colorPantalones == "darkblue")) {
        alert("Pareces un pitufo. ¡No gracias!");
    } else if ((colorCuerpo == "black") && (colorPantalones == "black")) {
        alert("¡Pon un poco de color!, aunque se respeta si te gusta ir de negro");
    } else if ((colorCuerpo == "darkblue") && (colorPantalones == "beige") && (colorZapatillas !== "White")) {
        alert("Me parece bien. Prueba con unas zapatillas blancas");  
    } else if ((colorCuerpo == "darkblue") && (colorPantalones == "beige") && (colorZapatillas == "White")) {
        alert("Me gusta tu estilo");                  
    } else {
        alert("algo es algo");
    }
}
```

La idea es que dependiendo de los colores que elijas, por ahora, te salga un alert diciendo si has combinado bien o mal y dando consejos.

Mi idea final es intentar poner % de acierto y un mensaje pero para eso aún me queda mucho.

Muchas gracias por todo la verdad!

Comment: Existen infinidad de formas de lograr lo que quieres, todas basadas en opiniones. ¿Cuál es la duda concreta? ¿Qué está mal con tu código? ¿Hay algún problema? ¿Cuál?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! LA forma de decir gracias aca es votando positivamente las respuestas que te sirvieron y aceptando aquella que soluciono tu problema. En este codigo, ChangeColor hace siempre lo mismo y podria ser una sola funcion... en conjuntar... no se si tengas una solucion...

Comment: Mi duda es si se puede simplificar la última parte del código (condicionales) para no tener que hacer muchas líneas usando "muchísimas interacciones de colores" :D

Comment: Respecto a "changecolor", hay 4 ya que digamos que hay 4 "prendas de vestir" a la que les puedes cambiar el color. No se si me explico, en el codepen creo que se ve más claro :D

Comment: Puedes definir una función universal, pasándole como parámetro qué cosa quieres cambiar, hacer un `switch` y comprobar lo que has recibido

Comment: Me gusta la opción del `switch`, aún no tengo muy buen nivel pero estaré testeando hasta que logre realizarlo :D